# Display row-wise data into columns in Lightning component

Tags: soql, lightning, lightning-experience, aggregate, ui

I have requirement to display data in the following format in lightning account page:

|Year | Jan | Feb | ... | Dec |
|2016 | 100 | 120 | ... | 250 |
|2017 | 190 | 0   | ... | 0   |

*[No data recorded from Feb 2017 to Dec, hence zero]*

**Problem**

I am getting the data in row format as shown below:

Year|   Month|  COGS Amt|   Sales Amt| 
2015|   Jan|    221091.21|  173708.15|
2015|   Feb|    176478.09|  115018.33|
2015|   Mar|    230104.73|  184395.09|
...
2015|   Dec|    173587.96|  88755.64|
2016|   Jan|    160719.48|  185181.27|
...
2016|   Dec|    150186.54|  151175.01|
2017|   Jan|    0|  36614.77|

> Component

```
<aura:component controller="SalesSummaryTablesCtr" 
                implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,force:hasRecordId" 
                access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="SalesSummaries" type="AggregateResult[]"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <table >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>COGS Amt</th>
                <th>Sales Amt</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.SalesSummaries}" var="summary">
                <tr>

                    <td>{!summary.Year}</td>
                    <td>{!if(summary.Month == 1, 'Jan'
                        , if(summary.Month == 2, 'Feb'
                        , if(summary.Month == 3, 'Mar'
                        , if(summary.Month == 4, 'Apr'
                        , if(summary.Month == 5, 'May'
                        , if(summary.Month == 6, 'Jun'
                        , if(summary.Month == 7, 'Jul'
                        , if(summary.Month == 8, 'Aug'
                        , if(summary.Month == 9, 'Sep'
                        , if(summary.Month == 10, 'Oct'
                        , if(summary.Month == 11, 'Nov', 'Dec')))))))))))}</td>
                    <td>{!summary.COGS_Amount}</td>
                    <td>{!summary.Amount}</td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>   

</aura:component>
```

> Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event) {
        var action = component.get("c.findAll");
        action.setParams({
            "accountId": component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            component.set("v.SalesSummaries", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

> Apex Controller

```
public class SalesSummaryTablesCtr {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<AggregateResult> findAll(Id accountId) {
        return [SELECT 
                  Sum(Cogs_Amount__c) COGS_Amount
                , Sum(Amount__c) Amount
                , Account__r.Name Name
                , Calendar_Month( Date__c ) Month
                , Calendar_Year( Date__c ) Year
                FROM Sales_Order_Summary__c 
                WHERE Date__c <= This_Year
                AND Date__c >= LAST_N_YEARS:2
                AND Account__c =: accountId
                GROUP BY Calendar_Year(Date__c), Calendar_Month( Date__c ), Account__r.Name        
               ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement some model.

```
public class SalesSummaryTablesCtr {

@AuraEnabled
public class Model{
    public Integer year;
    public Map<Integer, Decimal> dataMap;
    public Model(Integer y, Map<Integer, Decimal> d){
        year = y;
        dataMap = d;
    }
}
public static List<Model> getModels(Id accountId) {
    List<AggregateResult> agrs = [SELECT 
              Sum(Cogs_Amount__c) COGS_Amount
            , Sum(Amount__c) Amount
            , Calendar_Month( Date__c ) Month
            , Calendar_Year( Date__c ) Year
            FROM Sales_Order_Summary__c 
            WHERE Date__c <= This_Year
            AND Date__c >= LAST_N_YEARS:2
            AND Account__c =: accountId
            GROUP BY Calendar_Year(Date__c), Calendar_Month( Date__c ) ORDER BY Calendar_Year(Date__c), Calendar_Month( Date__c )
           ];
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Decimal>> simpleMap = new Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Decimal>>();
    for ( AggregateResult a: agrs ) {
        Integer year = Integer.valueOf( a.get('Year') );
        Integer month = Integer.valueOf( a.get('Month') );
        Map<Integer, Decimal> innerMap = simpleMap.get( year );
        if ( innerMap == null ) innerMap = new Map<Integer, Decimal>();
        innerMap.put( month, Decimal.valueOf( a.get( 'Amount' ) ) );
        simpleMap.put( year, innerMap );
    }
    List<Model> toReturn = new List<Model>();
    for ( Integer key: simpleMap.keySet() ) {
        toReturn.add( new Model( key, simpleMap.get( key ) ) );
    }
    return toReturn;
}
}
```

Then in component you just need to use that model list.

```
            <aura:attribute name="SalesSummaries" type="SalesSummaryTablesCtr.Model[]"/>

            <aura:iteration items="{!v.SalesSummaries}" var="summary">
            <tr>

                <td>{!summary.Year}</td>
               <aura:iteration items="{!summary.dataMap}" var="value">
                <td>{!value}</td>
        </aura:iteration>
        </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
```